# contiguous date ranges error in Powerpivot

Tags: date, powerpivot

I have a data sales "data" table, and a calendar table with every day in it.  The tables are linked and I have the calendar table marked as a date table and the unique identifier setup as date.

I'm trying to do things like year over year calculations, and for some dates it works, and for others I get the contiguous dates error.

Also, it works sometimes.  For example, I can do 6/1/16 to 5/31/17, but as soon as I add in 5/1/16 to 5/31/17 I get the error.

```
=CALCULATE([Total Sales], DATESYTD(Calendar[Date] )  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is here

https://powerpivotpro.com/2014/01/defanging-the-contiguous-date-selections-error/?nabm=1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F